# c# FTP File Download Times out

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I am downloading a file from my FTP Server. When it gets to the last bytes it freezes and times out. I had to set the timeout to -1 so it won't time out but the last bytes never finish.

Any ideas?

```
      FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://xxx" + "/" + fileDownload);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx");
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.KeepAlive = true;

            request.Timeout = -1;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            FileStream writer = File.Create(@"c:\temp\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileDownload) + ".csv");


            long length = response.ContentLength;
            int bufferSize = 2048;
            int readCount;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

           // readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (responseStream.CanRead)
            {
                readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                writer.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);

            }     
            responseStream.Close();
            response.Close();

            writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

[`CanRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canread.aspx) does not do what you think it does.  It just indicates whether a stream can in fact be read from *at all*.  Not whether there are any remaining bytes.  Instead rewrite your loop like this:

```
for (int readCount; (readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0;) 
{ 
    writer.Write(buffer, 0, readCount); 
}
```

Comment: Trying it now. I got done using Filezilla and i'm missing about 3000 bytes. I hope it works. thanks.

Comment: Also, unless you really need to buffer. you can simply do `responseStream.CopyTo(writer);`

Comment: @jojaba, yes, good advice. (assuming the OP is using .Net >= 4)

Comment: I have no need for a buffer. can you show an example? using .Net 4.5

Comment: @AndreDeMattia, jojaba already posted a complete example.  (yes it really is that concise)

Comment: cool, the file still freezes with just about 3000 bytes left. trying it without a buffer now

Comment: Still freezing up at the same place. This happens to a lot of files on the ftp server. Could it be the FTP server that has the issue? Filezilla works.

Comment: If it's freezing up with `.CopyTo` then it's definitely not your code that's a problem.

Comment: its about 150 bytes short and it's just sitting there. I am using .CopyTo :/

Comment: @AndreDeMattia, have you considered disabling your anti-virus (if any)?  I know that's solved this sort of problem for me before.

Comment: I'll try that now. File is 80 mg so it takes a half hour to dl.

Comment: same thing. -365 bytes short. It's still sitting like it's downloading the file. I set the timeout to -1 because it would time out before.  Some files download others don't. odd..